# Srucāvatī is Drona's sister?

Tags: mahabharata, dronacharya

In Shalya parva, Vaishampayana [narrates](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m09/m09048.htm) how Balarama went to sacred thirthas. The story of [Srucāvatī](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs09047.htm) (Sruvavati) is narrated there.
Her birth is exactly same as of Drona: pot born after Bharadwaja's *retu* fell, he stored in a pot. It is the same Apasara as well.

> The vital seed of the regenerate and high-souled Rishi Bharadwaja fell, upon beholding the large-eyed Apsara Ghritachi as the latter was passing at one time. That foremost of ascetics thereupon held it in his hand. It was then kept in a cup made of the leaves of a tree. In that cup was born the girl Sruvavati.

So, twins were born and Drona had a sister whom normally not mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily.

Dronacharya got his name from the fact that Bharadwaja’s seed was kept in  pot made of **Drona** patra .(The botanical name of this plant is *Leucas cephalotes*)

Two children are siblings because they share the same father,**and** they share the same mother(**’s womb**).

Srucavati was also borne of Bharadwaja’s seed,when he saw Ghritachi,but since she is not mentioned to have been in the same pot made of *Drona patra*,she can at best be considered as a **half sister** of Drona ,via Bharadwaja,and not a **full** sister,as the pot can be taken as the womb.